# how to dump/restore a HDD parttition tabel from the command-line (Bash)

Tags: windows, bash, backup, ubuntu-18.04

I have a small collection of Linux/Windows systems that I like to back up using Bash scripts.  I like to back up everything, not just user data, so I use things like dd and ntfsclone.  The details are different for each system, so to avoid confusion and errors I like to have it scripted.

I'm pretty happy with everything except the backup and possible restore of the partition tables on my drives.  There is a mix of MBR and GPT disks.

I'm most familiar with Bash and Python for scripting, but will take whatever works.  I'd like something that can be started (with backup media mounted) and left unattended.

Is there something that can do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into sfdisk(8). Examples from man page:

```
sfdisk --dump /dev/sda > sda.dump # writes ascii description of partition layout to file
sfdisk /dev/sda < sda.dump # parses ascii description of partition layout from file
```

I would probably suggest using the --backup option instead of the above commands. The --backup option causes the actual contents of the partition table to be stored, rather than regenerating it from parsing the text file.